# Django Rest Framework token auth

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I know this question has been answered before but the answer did not cover my confusion.

So I have a view that checks if the user is correct with username and password-

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def example_view(request, format=None):
  username = request.data.get("username")
  password = request.data.get("password")
  content = {}
  try:
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    if user.check_password(password):
      content = {'user': unicode(user.username),'token': unicode(user.auth_token),}
    else:
      content = {'wrong password'}
  except User.DoesNotExist:
    content = {
        'not registered',
        }
  return Response(content)
```

I make a post request and return the token if the username and password is right.

Now I made a model-

```
class Check(models.Model):
  owner = models.ForeignKey(User,verbose_name = 'UserName')
  mood = models.TextField(null=True)
```

And I have a function for the same model-

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def CheckApi(request):
  authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
  permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

  ?? query_set = Check.objects.get(owner=

  serializer = CheckSerializer(qs, many=True)
  return Response(serializer.data)
```

And serializer for it-

```
class CheckSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Check
    fields = ('__all__')
```

What I basically want to do is after a user has been **authenticated**, I want the api to return data for **that** user rather than returning data for all of the users.

Answer (score 0):

request object will contain the user(request.user).

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api-policy-decorators

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@authentication_classes(TokenAuthentication,)
@permissions_classes(IsAuthenticated,)
def CheckApi(request):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    query_set = Check.objects.get(owner=request.user)

    serializer = CheckSerializer(qs, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

If you plan to use the class viewsets, overload get_queryset to allow access to only user's objects.